# Sort react-table at mount component

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I'm trying to display a table that shows some data, but my data comes from backend sorted with case sensitive, but I don't want that, so, react-table sort default ignore case sensitive and I want to use that sort algorithm to sort data at component mount, but at documentation I couldn't find some informations to do that, I've tried to use Functional Rendering but without success.

```
<ReactTable data={data} columns={columns}>
  {(state, makeTable, instance) => {
   instance.sortData()
   return makeTable()
  }
</ReactTable>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried this kind of solutions ?

```
<ReactTable 
   data={data} 
   columns={columns} 
   sorted={[
     {
      id: 'lastName',
      desc: true
     }
   ]} ></ReactTable>
```

Comment: Thank you dude! I'm forgot that property, works like a charm now.

Comment: @JoãoVictor Did you mean to say that you're all 'sorted' now?

Comment: ‍♀️‍♀️ Oh no you didn't @Tejogol...